# Loop through 2x two-dimensional arrays to compare

Tags: php, arrays

Good morning, for an stock inventory I want to update it automaticaly when we sell a car. I have 2x two-dimensional arrays:

```
$array_purchase = array(
    array(
        'Name' => 'Mercedes',
        'Purchase' => 10
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'BMW',
        'Purchase' => 20
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'FIAT',
        'Purchase' => 30
)
);


$array_sales = array(
    array(
        'Name' => 'Mercedes',
        'Purchase' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'Name' => 'BMW',
        'Purchase' => 10
    )
);
```

I tried to use this, but didn't work for me:

```
foreach($array_sales as $sName => $sSold){

    if(isset($array_purchase[$sName])){
        $array_purchase[$sName] - $sSold;
    }

}
```

The results should something like

> Mercedes: 5x ***(10-5)***
>
> Fiat: 30x ***(30 - 0)***
>
> BMW: 10x ***(20 - 10)***

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to keep your data structured that way, then this is your solution:

**Code:**

```
foreach ( $array_sales as $keySales => $sales ) {

    foreach ( $array_purchase as $keyPurchase => &$purchase ) {
        if ( $purchase[ 'Name' ] == $sales[ 'Name' ] ) {
            $purchase[ 'Purchase' ] -= $sales[ 'Purchase' ];
            //break the 2nd foreach
            break;
        }
    }
    //unset the reference!
    unset ( $purchase );
}

print_r( $array_purchase );
```

**The result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Mecedes
            [Purchase] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => BMW
            [Purchase] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => FIAT
            [Purchase] => 30
        )

)
```

You lack a bit of understanding of arrays in php, there are some good examples on the net, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, just google some.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array_purchase as $key => $value){
   if(isset($array_sales[$key]['Purchase'])){
      echo($array_purchase[$key]['Name']." ".($array_purchase[$key]['Purchase'] - $array_sales[$key]['Purchase']));
      echo("<br />");
   } else {
      echo($array_purchase[$key]['Name']." ".$array_purchase[$key]['Purchase']);
      echo("<br />");
   }
};
```

This code can offcourse be optimized a lot, but it will give you a good idea how you should loop through the data.

Comment: This solution assumes that the 2 arrays have ALWAYS the same keys(indexes) in both arrays. Which I am not sure that is realistic.

Comment: That was not a requirement. @Klodoma

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the multi dimensional array into a single dimension array and then do a simple substract operation on the purchase array:

```
$array_purchase = transformToSingleDimension($array_purchase);
$array_sales = transformToSingleDimension($array_sales);

$result = arraySubstract($array_purchase, $array_sales);

var_dump($result);

function transformToSingleDimension($array)
{
    return array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $item) {
        $carry[$item['Name']] = $item['Purchase'];
        return $carry;
    }, array());
}

function arraySubstract($array1, $array2)
{
    foreach ($array1 as $key => &$value) {
        if (isset($array2[$key])) {
            $value -= $array2[$key];
        }
    }

    return $array1;
}
```

The result would be:

```
array(3) { ["Mecedes"]=> int(5) ["BMW"]=> int(10) ["FIAT"]=> int(30) }
```